# What is the function of JobBuilderFactory.get(job).incrementer(RunIdIncrementer)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm developing a Spring-Batch project using Spring-Boot and everything is going along nicely. I've done a few spring-batch examples (including some from spring.io), but I'm not sure what some of the stuff does, and "it just works" doesn't satiate me.

My spring boot main class implements `CommandLineRunner` and for this particular job the initial set up looked like

```
@Bean
public Job myJob(JobExecutionListenerSupport listener) {
    return myJobBuilderFactory.get(JOB)
            .listener(listener)
            .start(myStep())
            .build();
}
```

Which caused

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.bjc.providermodel.maintenance.MaintenanceApplication.main(MaintenanceApplication.java:20) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=99, version=0, Job=[myJob]
```

Why does changing the above bean to

```
@Bean
public Job myJob(JobExecutionListenerSupport listener) {
    return myJobBuilderFactory.get(JOB)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .start(myStep())
            .build();
}
```

Make everything go smoothly? I attempted to read up on the doc for `RunIdIncrementer` and also read up a little [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html). From what I can tell it needs this incrementer to keep track of a particular set of jobs that are running to do "stuff", but not sure what stuff is exactly. The Spring-Boot abstraction is making it hard for me to know what's going on here

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This isn't a "Boot thing" as much as it is a "Batch thing".  Spring Batch has the rule that a `JobInstance` can only be run once to completion.  This means that for each combination of identifying job parameters, you can only have one `JobExecution` that results in `COMPLETE`.  A `RunIdIncrementer` will append an additional, unique parameter to the list of parameters so that the resulting combination would be unique...giving you a new `JobInstance` each time you ran the job with the same combination of identifying parameters.

The `RunIdIncrementer` is really just a special case of the `JobParametersIncrementer` which you can read more about in our documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#JobParametersIncrementer).

Comment: Given your explanation, should the sentence in the docs you referred to - `"Unlike JobLauncher (which requires a new JobParameters object that triggers a new JobInstance), if the parameters are different from any previous set of parameters, the startNextInstance method uses the JobParametersIncrementer tied to the Job to force the Job to a new instance:..."` read instead: "Unlike JobLauncher (which requires a new JobParameters object that triggers a new JobInstance), if the parameters are ***not*** different from any previous ..."?

Comment: Also, why, in this case, is the responsibility to add that extra `Job` attribute - incrementer - left to the framework's user, sounds like the framework should be able to decide to add it internally without any end user's involvement?  Or am I not reading it right?