# Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I know this has been asked many time but I could not 
find answer for I problem. I am Trying to schedule my spring batch for every 20 second but its getting fail.

QuartzConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private JobLocator jobLocator;

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobfactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobfactory.setJobClass(QuartzJobLauncher.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("jobName", "Test_Job");
        map.put("jobLauncher", jobLauncher);
        map.put("jobLocator", jobLocator);
        jobfactory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        jobfactory.setGroup("group");
        jobfactory.setName("job");
        return jobfactory;
    }

    // Job is scheduled after every 20 sec
    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean ctFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        ctFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        ctFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        ctFactory.setName("cron_trigger");
        ctFactory.setGroup("cron_group");
        ctFactory.setCronExpression("0/20 * * * * ?");
        return ctFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

QuartzJobLauncher.java

```
public class QuartzJobLauncher extends QuartzJobBean {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzJobLauncher.class);

    private String jobName;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobLocator jobLocator;

    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }
    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }
    public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }
    public JobLocator getJobLocator() {
        return jobLocator;
    }
    public void setJobLocator(JobLocator jobLocator) {
        this.jobLocator = jobLocator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            Job job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            log.info("{}_{} was completed successfully", job.getName(), jobExecution.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Encountered job execution exception!");
        }

    }

}
```

BatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Tasklet task1()
    {
        return new Tasklet(){

            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("hello world");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public Step step1(){

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(task1())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job1()
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }


}
```

BatchApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(QuartzConfiguration.class)
public class BatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

error log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-07-11 14:35:59.370  INFO 8868 --- [           main] com.schwab.cat.BatchApplication          : Starting BatchApplication on KVMOF0487DVLBDC with PID 8868 (started by pankaj.k.singh in C:\Users\pankaj.k.singh\Desktop\batch\sample hello world)
2017-07-11 14:35:59.377  INFO 8868 --- [           main] com.schwab.cat.BatchApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-11 14:35:59.511  INFO 8868 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@221af3c0: startup date [Tue Jul 11 14:35:59 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-11 14:36:00.992  WARN 8868 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-07-11 14:36:01.013  WARN 8868 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-07-11 14:36:01.230  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.253  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bb5301] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.435  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.632  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSource' of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.641  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3aef661] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.672  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSourceInitializer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.679  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17e2d67] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.718  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobLauncher' of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.732  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:01.733  INFO 8868 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.quantvalley.batch.quartz.QuartzConfiguration' of type [com.quantvalley.batch.quartz.QuartzConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88291ebb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-11 14:36:03.256  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2017-07-11 14:36:03.606  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2017-07-11 14:36:03.912  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2017-07-11 14:36:03.980  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2017-07-11 14:36:03.984  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.3 created.
2017-07-11 14:36:03.987  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore             : RAMJobStore initialized.
2017-07-11 14:36:03.991  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.3) 'schedulerFactoryBean' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2017-07-11 14:36:03.993  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'schedulerFactoryBean' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2017-07-11 14:36:03.993  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.3
2017-07-11 14:36:03.998  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@20312893
2017-07-11 14:36:04.335  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]
2017-07-11 14:36:04.366  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 25 ms.
2017-07-11 14:36:04.733  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-07-11 14:36:04.748  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2017-07-11 14:36:04.749  INFO 8868 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2017-07-11 14:36:04.750  INFO 8868 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2017-07-11 14:36:04.773  INFO 8868 --- [           main] com.schwab.cat.BatchApplication          : Started BatchApplication in 6.481 seconds (JVM running for 11.417)
2017-07-11 14:36:20.039 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
2017-07-11 14:36:40.006 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-2] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
2017-07-11 14:37:00.001 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-3] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
2017-07-11 14:37:20.002 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-4] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
2017-07-11 14:37:40.002 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-5] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
2017-07-11 14:38:00.002 ERROR 8868 --- [ryBean_Worker-6] c.q.batch.quartz.QuartzJobLauncher       : Encountered job execution exception!
```

Please someone look into it and let me know the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You swallowed the exception in your try/catch and instead, you logged only the fact that exception occurrent, but not what kind of exception it was. If you change logging statement to this:

```
log.error("Encountered job execution exception!", e);
```

You'll see that the error says:

`org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [Test_Job] was registered`

You have declared a job with name `job1`, not `Test_Job` so that's why you're getting the exception. You have to change job data map to:

```
map.put("jobName", "job1");
```

This will remove the exception, but your job will still run once as Spring Batch requires unique job parameters to restart it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368027/1126831) for explanation.
So because of that, you have to modify your job execution to something like this (the simplest) to be able to run it continually:

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        Job job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);
        Map<String, JobParameter> parametersMap = new HashMap<>();
        parametersMap.put("timestamp", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parametersMap);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        log.info("{}_{} was completed successfully", job.getName(), jobExecution.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Encountered job execution exception!", e);
    }
}
```